# How To Get My OnItemClickListener To Work And Show Toast with Item Position?

Tags: java, android, adt, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

Im Trying To do customList With icons i Used Custom View To make icon+text
now Im Trying to get The Items In the List To respond To OnItemClickListener 
its not Responding And Not Showing My Toast With The Position Of The Item

Please Help .

```
    ////////////////////////////////////THIS IS My Main Activity///////////////////
    package com.example.mycash;

    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.DataSetObserver;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener  {
                DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
                ListView listView;
                AdapterList adapterList;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         //Hide Action Bar--------------------------------------   
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.hide();
        //Hide Action Bar---------------------------------------  
           listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listMenu);
           final AdapterList adapterList = new AdapterList(this);
           listView.setAdapter(adapterList);


           drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout); 


        }//OnCreate Closing...

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), adapterList.menu[position] + "Test" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }  
    }



////////////////This IS My AdapterList Class here Im Creating Custom adapter///////////////////
package com.example.mycash;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AdapterList extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;

    String[] menu = {"How Much Did I Work"
            ,"Add/Edit Work Space"
            ,"My Profile"
            ,"Send Work Doc Via Mail"
            ,"Send FeedBack"
            ,"Bug Report"};
     int[] icons = {R.drawable.clock,R.drawable.edit,R.drawable.profile,R.drawable.mail,R.drawable.sendfeed,R.drawable.bug};

    public AdapterList(Context context){
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return menu.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return menu[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // Not In Use  For Future Uses...
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = null;
        if(convertView == null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_layout, null);

        }else{
             row = null;
        }
        TextView customTextView = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.customText1);
        ImageView customImageView = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.customImage1);

        customTextView.setText(menu[position]);
        customImageView.setImageResource(icons[position]);

        return row;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

you must set onItemClick listener to listview:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the listView on event listener(`OnItemClickListner`) yet, Do this and it should work.